ValueError: Pickle Deserialization Security Warning
TypeError: FAISS.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_dangerous_deserialization'
Based on the error message provided, I inferred that the code was attempting to load a pickle file using the FAISS.load_local() function, but it was encountering an error related to deserialization. The error message suggested that setting allow_dangerous_deserialization to True could resolve the issue.
My response aimed to provide guidance on how to modify the code to address this error by setting allow_dangerous_deserialization to True. Additionally, I emphasized the importance of trusting the source of the data before enabling dangerous deserialization, as it could potentially execute arbitrary code.
Overall, I expected that modifying the code as suggested would resolve the deserialization error, allowing the pickle file to be loaded successfully.

I don't see the question here, mate.
Well what you did was pass allow_dangerous_deserialization=True and I believe it looks something like this: FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)
One thing to note, you should know what data you are passing or perform few fail-checks before actually passing it by checking what model or data you are using to load data.
